# Prevent action to be trigged when the form is invalid

Tags: ember.js, parsley.js

I am using parsleyjs to validate my form and I would like to know if there is a way to prevent ember action to be called when the form is invalid.

Comment: Yes I have tried to validate the form from the action however I wasnt able to find a way to pass the form object to controller action

Answer (score 1):

Validate form in your action, show error message and call `return;`, if form is invalid.

Comment: In addition: have the 'submit' button disabled by default, and remove the disabled attribute when there are no errors. `Ember.Computed` can assist here to determine this and disable/enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have tried to validate the form from the action however I wasnt able to find a way to pass the form object to controller action

```
<script>

    var parlseyForm;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        parsleyForm = $("#editLeagueForm").parsley();
    });

</script>


<div class="mbs-btn-bar">

    <button class="btn btn-default" role="button" {{action "cancel"}}>{{t 'action.cancel'}}</button>
    <!--
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="validateForm(this)">{{t 'action.update'}}</button>
    -->

    <button type="button" id="updateLeague" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" {{action "updateLeague" parsleyForm}}>{{t 'action.update'}}</button>
</div>

actions: {
    /**
     * This action is responsible to update the league.
     */
    updateLeague: function (form) {

        alert(form); //undefined

        this.get('model').save().then(() => {
            if (this.isNewFile()) {
                this.uploadAvatar();
            } else {
                this.notifyRoute('league', 'info.league.updated');
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.handleError(error, 'error.system_error');
        });
    },
```